# Rails controller looks like it is saving all params, but fields are missing when I pull the record - Like post function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am keeping an eye on my rails server and my rails console. Everything looks great in my server.

When I go to create a Like, my server saves all the stuff I'm looking to save.

Notice that I am passing in an `author_id`, a `likable_id`, and a `likable_type`. This association is polymorphic.

```
Like Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "likes" ("author_id", "likeable_type", "likeable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["author_id", 1], ["likeable_type", "Pin"], ["likeable_id", 34], ["created_at", "2020-12-18 04:52:49.973371"], ["updated_at", "2020-12-18 04:52:49.973371"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/api/likes_controller.rb:8
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/api/likes_controller.rb:8
  Rendering api/likes/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered api/likes/_like.json.jbuilder (0.4ms)
  Rendered api/likes/show.json.jbuilder (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 20.6ms)
```

Great! I get the 200OK! Awesome.

However, when I check `Like.all` in the console, It looks like the Like is being created with none of the params I passed into it above.

```
[55] pry(main)> Like.all
  Like Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes"
=> [#<Like:0x00007fbef776c7e0
  id: 6, #<--- Only the id for the like is being shown :(
  created_at: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 04:30:50 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 18 Dec 2020 04:30:50 UTC +00:00>]
[56] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For whatever reason, my schema was not bugged out and somehow had extra text. I dropped the table and re-migrated.